# can't connect multiple database in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I wanted to use two databases from `mongodb` using `createConnection` over `mongoose`.

```
exports.mongooseMaster = mongoose.createConnection('mongodb://192.168.2.10:27017/Master', function (err, res) {
   if (err) {
      console.log ('ERROR connecting to: remote Master ' + err);
  } else {
      console.log ('Successfully connected to: remote Master');
  }
});

// Connect to Database
exports.mongoosetime = mongoose.createConnection('mongodb://192.168.2.10:27017/Planner2', function (err, res) {
if (err) {
      console.log ('ERROR connecting to: remote Planner2 ' + err);
  } else {
      console.log ('Successfully connected to: remote Planner2');
  };
});
```

When I execute this code, I see only Planner2 Database has created not Master database. But I get these line in console

```
Successfully connected to: remote Master
Successfully connected to: remote Planner2
```

What would be the problem?

Comment: Why do you want two connections though? Shouldn't getting different DB from the same connection be sufficient?